# Make image link with the same href using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make my img link to this same image. Unfortunately it is not working.

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" width="120" height="120" />
```

and this is what im trying to acheave:

```
<a href="someimage.jpg">
    <img src="images/6208606.jpg" width="120" height="120" />
</a>
```

but this don't seems to be working

```
var ImgScr = $('.gallery img').attr('scr');

$('.gallery img').wrap('<a></a>').attr('href', ImgScr);
```

Any help very appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wrap](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap#html) function doesn't return the newly created element so you are applying the `href` attribute to the `img` tag instead of the `anchor` tag. You may try this instead:

```
$('.gallery img').wrap($('<a></a>').attr('href', ImgScr));
```

Comment: So what method should it be? Result returns what im after to be honest

Comment: @Aaron, are you sure? console.log($('img').wrap('<a></a>')); prints "img" in my FireBug console.

Answer (score 6):

Shouldn't that be `attr('src')` and not `attr('scr')`?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('.gallery img').each(function(){
    src = ($(this).attr('src'));
    $(this).wrap($('<a></a>').attr('href', src));
});
```